# Android viewGroup issue - Testing with Appium

Tags: java, android, testing, xpath, appium

Very new to Automated testing.
Need the SWITCH option to be selected.
Struggling to write the code for it (Android).

[image]

Test failed due to this pop-up. "Switch" option needs to be selected.
Below are my test steps. Test fails at step "When I navigate to Notification Center after login"

[image]

[image]

CODE for that step in my java file. 
According to the below code if element notificationIconAfterLogin exists then click notificationHeader.

Here notificationIconAfterLogin has **xpath: (//android.widget.ImageView [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezUZ9.png) )[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ikGX.png)**
notificationHeader has **xpath: //*[@text='Notification Centre']**

Now notificationIconAfterLoginAndroidOptional has **xpath: (//android.view.ViewGroup [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ikGX.png) )[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezUZ9.png)**
switchDeviceBtn has **xpath: //*[@text='SWITCH']**

```
@Given("^I navigate to Notification Center after login$")
    public void iNavigateToNotificationCenterAfterLogin() throws Exception {
        if (elementExists(notificationIconAfterLogin)) {
            loopClickUntilFound(notificationIconAfterLogin, notificationHeader);
        } else {
            loopClickUntilFound(notificationIconAfterLoginAndroidOptional, switchDeviceBtn);
        }
        waitFor(3);
        screenshot(); // Cap screen in notification center
    }
```

[image]

My SWITCH option doesn't get selected.
Need help to fix the code.

what am I missing here?? is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

in the method iNavigateToNotificationCenterAfterLogin() first check if Switch option is displayed and then click on the Switch button and then perform your regular operation

Sample Apium-Java Code:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@text='SWITCH']")).size()==1)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='SWITCH']")).click()
}
```